# Can the ASP.NET Entity Framework automatically generate data annotations?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

My team is writing a large scale business website in ASP.NET MVC 4 using the database-first approach. Does anyone know if it's possible to have data annotations automatically generated based on the database schema? It seems redundant to have to manually write the "buddy" metadata classes containing the data annotations when the framework should be aware of a database column's properties and make these part of the POCO classes it generates. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is an interesting question for many reasons. Before you dive too deeply into Buddy Classes and Entities heavy with data annotations, ask yourself how often you will find yourself using Entities for your Presentation Layer. I find all too frequently I use custom Models b/c my view are rarely as straight forward as my Data.

Comment: Dave - are you saying that you generally don't use models that are auto-generated by the entity framework?

Comment: correct, i usually dont use EF Entities for View Models. More often I create Models that include Entities or Models that are similar but better suited to the View.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at LINQ to SQL.
You can use it to create a .dbml file in a graphical editor by dragging the tables from the server explorer.

Here's the MSDN [How to: Create LINQ to SQL Classes in a Web Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907587%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I have only minimal knowledge of LINQ to SQL so I'll do some investigating on that.

Comment: I've added a link for you then.

Comment: Thank you flup that was helpful. I created a dbml to see how it would work and there were my column data types, max lengths, etc right there on the properties that were created! However I think we're more interested in the flexibility and loose coupleing of the entity framework.

Comment: New answer coming up then!

Answer (score 1):

1) The framework does a good job of extrapolating data annotation based on table structure, but they won't be perfect.

2) Sadly, when you reach a point when you want to customize more than the framework, you are stuck with Buddy classes. They're a bit tedious but so far the best method I've found for customizing data annotation.

3) All too often, I find myself gravitating toward custom classes and away from generated POCO's. The reason is usually the differences between storing and displaying. In entry screens

1. I will often break up phone #'s into 3 textboxes.
2. Lookups for foreign keys require select lists (often added to model).
3. Often I'll pass other values that may be relevant to my View functionality but not specific to the storage table (display fields, navigation / bread crumbs)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Database First approach with the Entity Framework.
You can generate the entity model from an existing database using the entity data model wizard.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj206878

Comment: This is what we have been doing, unfortunately it doesn't automatically add the data annotations to the model based on the db schema. Which really sucks. =)

Comment: Including the DBContext generator?

Comment: It appears not. I created a quick project using the DbContext Generator and aside from Nullable there were no other attributes gleaned from the schema. Unless I'm doing something wrong...

Answer (score 0):

@Kerezo covers pretty much exactly what you want to do here: [Add Data Annotation To Entity Framework(Or Linq to SQL) generated class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978608/add-data-annotation-to-entity-frameworkor-linq-to-sql-generated-class)

It is not possible to auto generate the data annotations automatically.